# What is the thermal average of time-dependent Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$Let $H(t)$ be a time-dependent Hamiltonian. Then what does it mean to calculate the thermal average?

**My thought process**.
Usually, if $H$ is time-independent, this would just mean
$$
\langle A\rangle= \frac{1}{Z} \tr(e^{-\beta H}A)
$$
So it seems that the reasonable answer would to just replace $H\mapsto H(t)$ so that the thermal average is now time-dependent too. However, this doesn't seem to be the correct formulation in linear response theory. Indeed, in the context of linear response where $H(t) = H_0 +f(t)A$ where $f$ is real function depending on time, we see that
$$
Z(t) \equiv \tr e^{-\beta H(t)}=Z_0\langle T_\tau \exp \left(-f(t)\int_0^\beta A(\tau)d\tau \right)\rangle_0, \qquad A(\tau)=e^{H_0\tau}Ae^{-H_0\tau}
$$
Yet, in textbooks (e.g., Coleman. Many-body Physics), we see that $f(t)$ is put inside the imaginary time integral and replaced with $f(\tau)$, which results in the RHS being independent of time $t$, i.e.,
$$
Z_0\langle T_\tau \exp \left(-\int_0^\beta f(\tau)A(\tau)d\tau \right)\rangle_0 
$$
The above is equal to
$$
Z\equiv\tr \left( T_\tau \exp \left(-\int_0^\beta H(\tau)d\tau \right)\right)
$$
This would imply that the termal average of time-dependent Hamiltonian would be something like
$$
\langle A\rangle=\frac{1}{Z} \tr\left( A\cdot T_\tau \exp \left(-\int_0^\beta H(\tau)d\tau \right)\right)
$$
I understand that if $H(t)= H$ was time-independent (e.g., $H=H_0 +fA$ where $f$ is a constant), then
$$
T_\tau \exp \left(-\int_0^\beta H(\tau)d\tau \right) = e^{-\beta H}
$$
Hence, the formula above reduces to what we expect in the time-independent case. However, I'm confused about the motivation of the time-dependent formulation.

Comment: Such thermal averaging doesn't make much sense. Either there are supplementary conditions (e.g., that the change is slow compared to the relaxation processes) or it is a formal step for convenience of derivation. This is not a standard derivation of the linear response.

Comment: @Vadim Could you elaborate on the standard deviation for nonzero temperature case?

Comment: Usually the operator of interest is time-dependent, i.e., its evolution is governed by $H_0 + H_1(t)$, but the averaging is over an equilibrium ensemble $e^{-\beta H_0}$. Although one may want to use formal averaging over the time-dependent Hamiltonian to silplify the math (keeping in mind that in the end one will keep only the first order terms in the perturbation).